# Back button for Image picker intent

Tags: android

When the user clicks a button it opens an image picker but if the user hits the back button, instead of returning to the activity, it finishes. This is how I start the image picker:

```
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the intended behavior. So you need to override the method `onBackPressed`, capture the event and put the code to return to the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("mylog", "Back button pressed!");
   //your code to go to previous
}
```

Comment: my activity override for onBakPressed does not seem to execute when the user presses back while on the image selector intent

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can handle back button while on gallery or camera or any other by this way.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) 
    {
    //Here you can handle,do anything you want
    }
//other code
}
```